# How would I use this?

Tags: lua, obfuscation

I'm trying to use this 'advanced lua obfuscator' named XFuscator to obfuscate some code I created. However, I am not sure about how to go about using this. Could you guys give me a brief explanation? Here's the github link: https://github.com/mlnlover11/XFuscator

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't come with documentation?  How would you expect "us" to know?

Answer (score 2):

1. Download XFuscator source code to your computer.
2. Fix error in the file `XFuscator\Step2.lua` (see below)
3. Open console and `cd` to XFuscator root directory (where `README.txt` is located)
4. Run `lua XFuscator.lua "path\to\your_program.lua"` (lua should be in your PATH)
5. See the result (obfuscated program) is in `path\to\your_program [Obfuscated].lua`

Please note that obfuscated program can run only on the same OS and on the same Lua version (obfuscated program is heavily depends on `math.random()` and `math.randomseed()` behavior, these functions are OS-dependent and Lua-dependent).

You can play with option `-uglify` and levels of obfuscation (see usage message inside `XFuscator.lua`)

---

*About the error:*
In the file `XFuscator/Step2.lua` the logic of [lines #5,#6,#12](https://github.com/mlnlover11/XFuscator/blob/master/XFuscator/Step2.lua#L5-L6) is incorrect:

- Line #12 of `Step2.lua` uses the number intact (double has 17 digits precision), while only 14 digits (that's the default Lua number format) are saved into obfuscated file on line #6.  This inconsistency sometimes leads to different pseudorandom sequence and you see error message `attempt to call a nil value` when trying to execute your obfuscated program.
- Not all Lua implementations are sensitive to fractional part of a number given as an argument to `math.randomseed()`; for example, PUC Lua simply ignores fractional part, only low 32-bits of integer part are accepted as seed (unfortunately, Lua manual keeps silence about that).  So, it is better for the seed to be an integer.

*How to fix the error:*
Replace line #5

```
local __X = math.random()
```

with the following line:

```
local __X = math.random(1, 9^9)
```

Comment: Sorry for the super late response, but when I do the last thing (Run lua XFuscator.lua "path\to\your_program.lua" (lua should be in your PATH)) it says "'lua' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is your lua executable?  Try `lua.exe` or `lua53.exe` to `c:\full\path\to\lua.exe`.

Comment: I ran this:
`lua XFuscator.lua "C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\XFuscator-master.new.lua"`

Comment: Do you have Lua installed?  Where does Lua executable located on your computer?  Search for `lua*.exe` file.

Comment: I can't find that.

Comment: Install LuaJIT (XFuscator requires Lua 5.1 + bit library).  Or run XFuscator on the target system (if it is a plugin for a game)

Comment: I tried using the old version, attempting to obfuscate 'print("Hello world")' but the code was WAY too long for me to actually use. That's why I was trying to use the new version because you can modify that (I think). I installed LuaJIT but it's just in it's rar file right now, I'm not sure what to do with it. Can you help me with that?
Also, here's 1.0 (the old version)
http://pastebin.com/Su9zS7E6

Comment: Xfuscator generates long code, that's on purpose and is absolutely normal.  Lua can run long programs.  To run LuaJIT, simply copy `luajit.exe` and `lua51.dll` to the current directory and run `luajit.exe program.lua arguments`.